# Expected value of $2^X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

If I have to calculate $\mathrm{E}(2^X)$, is it then just $(2^{x_1} \cdot p_1) + (2^{x_2} \cdot p_2) + (2^{x_3} \cdot p_3)$ etc.?

Like $\mathrm{E}(X)$ is just $(x_1 \cdot p_1) + (x_2 \cdot p_2)$ etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is a discrete random variable, $$\Bbb E(f(X))=\sum_x f(x)P(X=x)$$

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. This is sometimes called the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). If it is a discrete distribution and one knows its probability mass function $f_X$ (but not $f_{g(X)}$), then the expected value of $g(X)$ is
$$
\operatorname{E}[g(X)] = \sum_x g(x) f_X(x)
$$
where the sum is over all possible values $x$ of $X$.